# Expected class or package adding a view using a class

Tags: java, android, class

I have a LinearLayout in my xml with id `@+id/layout` and I want to add another LinearLayout inside using this class:

```
public class Field{

    private Context context;
    private LinearLayout layo;

    public Field(Context con){
        context=con;
        layo=new LinearLayout(con);
    }
    public void build(LinearLayout layout){
        layo.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(layout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,layout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}
```

I am calling this class this way:

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
fields=new Field(this);
fields.build(layout);
```

But I am getting the following error on `layout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` and `layout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`:

> Expected class or package

Exactly here:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`layo` should be `layout` and `LayoutParams` constants need to be accessible.

```
public void build(LinearLayout layout){
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```